# Whenever I try to assign some modified value to a globally declared variable inside the script tag the script tag stops executing. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I try to assign some modified value to a globally declared variable inside the script tag the script tag stops executing. Why?

I am trying to assign a new date to the datetype variable inside script tag.
here is the code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
        $("#anchor").css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(".collapsible1").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("collapse1 expand");
            $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });

    $("#changecolor").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });

    $('#ChooseYourTimeBtn').click(function(){

       alert("abc")
           **commented line start** @*@StartDate=$("#testid1").val();
            @EndDate=$('#testid2').val();*@ *commented line ends*

    });
</script>
```

This code works perfectly. But if i try to assign some value into the variables and try to execute the whole script tag doesn't execute. Why?

Comment: Please reformat the code

Comment: What are you using for comment characters to comment out those lines?  Javascript comments are either `// single line comment` or `/* a comment here */`.

Comment: That I just wrote in the code so that people can easily point out the part that is commented out

Comment: Are you using `@EndDate` ASP.Net MVC? and trying to set server side variables?

Comment: no those variables are declared in the view page itself. there are two datepickers present in my view. I want the dates i select on those to be assigned to the two variables Startdate and Enddate on button click.

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my previous comment and answer that question.  If you are commenting them out wrong, that could be the entire source of your problem.

Comment: What do you see in the browser error console?  If there are script errors, then those should show in the console.  This should be one of the first steps you take when debugging a problem.

Comment: That is the part I added while posting the question. Let me state the problem again, while I am trying to assign some value to the global variable inside the script tag it doesn't work and whatever I have written before in the script tag also stops working. Could you please tell me how to solve that?

Comment: I'd suggest you go to View/Source in the browser (to see what code the browser actually sees) and then paste that code into your question.  We need to see the EXACT code that the browser sees to have an idea what is going wrong.  Right now you're question does not show exactly what the browser sees.

Comment: And you apparently have a script error and the browser console will tell you exactly what that script error is.

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't work since it won't compile as `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are invalid variable names.

Javascript variables can have letters, digits, dollar signs ($) and underscores (_). They can't have **at-the-rate** `@` symbol.

Refer to this [site](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) to check the validity of your variable names.

Comment: The OP says that the script stops working when they comment OUT those lines.  Doesn't make logical sense to me, but that's what the question says.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought he said that his code works perfectly till he/she remove comments. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes the variables are declared outside the script tag. I need to assign the values to the variables as written inside the commented section. but the whole script tag stops executing if i try to uncomment those. But the variables are accessible inside script tag,FYI.

Comment: `variables are declared outside the script tag` What kind of variables are these?

Comment: var StartDate=DateTime.now.day;

Comment: Well, the question states; ***But if i comment out the two assign statement lines and try to execute the whole script tag doesn't execute.***

Comment: @jfriend00 My bad. edited the question. and found the reason also. As I have declared the variables globally and assigned them with some default values, inside the script tag when i am tring to assign again another value it takes that I am trying to assign a value to a value,like 1=1. Kindly tell me how i can assign the values from the datepicker to those variables on button click

Comment: @jfriend00
@{var StartDate=DateTime.Now.Date;}

19-09-2016 00:00:00=$('#testid1').val();
           19-09-2016 00:00:00= $('#testid2').val();
the browser sees it as this.

Comment: @BiswajitChhotaray - Well, that's not even close to legal Javscript and the browser console would have told you exactly what the error was a long time ago.  You need to learn to look in the browser console for every error.

Comment: I have written the code like this:-
@{var StartDate=DateTime.Now.Date;} 

@StartDate=$('#testid1').val()

and the browser compiles it as

19-09-2016 00:00:00=$('#testid1').val();

and the error says unexpected number